# Could not autowire. There are more than one bean of type Jaxb2Marshaller

Tags: java, spring

I work with a Spring project where I have a main configuration class and 2 other configuration classes are extended from there. The sample code is provided below.

Comment: If these marshallers are specific to their clients, then why do they need to be beans at all? Could you instead simply let them be POJOs and call `brinkSales2Marshaller()` from your `@Bean Sales2Client` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, since you're create the `OrderingClient` and `Sales2Client` using `@Bean` methods, do not annotate them with `@Component`. Do one or the other, not both.

Second, you're auto-wiring by type, and there are two of them, so you need to add extra information to distinguish them. You can use `@Qualifier` on the parameter for that, see below.

However, the recommended way, when both beans are in the same `@Configuration` class, is to simply call the method, as shown in the [**Spring Documentation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-injecting-dependencies):

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller brinkOrderingMarshaller() {
    ...
}

@Bean
public OrderingClient brinkOrderingClient() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = brinkOrderingMarshaller();
    ...
}
```

#### Use @Qualifier

If you prefer to auto-wire parameter by type, you use `@Qualifier`, as mentioned earlier. There are multiple ways of doing it:

- Add `@Qualifier` to the `@Bean` method, so ambiguity is resolved by matching qualifiers:

  ```
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("foo")
  public Jaxb2Marshaller brinkOrderingMarshaller() {
      ...
  }

  @Bean
  public OrderingClient brinkOrderingClient(@Qualifier("foo") Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- `@Qualifier` also supports matching by bean name, and the *default* bean name is the name of the method:

  ```
  @Bean
  public Jaxb2Marshaller brinkOrderingMarshaller() {
      ...
  }

  @Bean
  public OrderingClient brinkOrderingClient(@Qualifier("brinkOrderingMarshaller") Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- You can also explicitly name the beans:

  ```
  @Bean("foo")
  public Jaxb2Marshaller brinkOrderingMarshaller() {
      ...
  }

  @Bean
  public OrderingClient brinkOrderingClient(@Qualifier("foo") Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- You can assign aliases to beans if you want a single bean to resolve multiple uses by different names:

  ```
  @Bean({"foo", "alias1", "alias2"})
  public Jaxb2Marshaller brinkOrderingMarshaller() {
      ...
  }

  @Bean
  public OrderingClient brinkOrderingClient(@Qualifier("alias2") Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
      ...
  }
  ```

Ambiguities can also be resolved using `@Primary`, but that's not applicable in your case.